# Prevent possible exception at std::list addition time

Tags: list, c++11, exception

I currently have a std::list that stores std::size_ts. I use a std::list (instead of a vector) because I don't need random access; I just keep appending to the end of the list, and I will only need to iterate through it once to go through the content before program terminates to perform some clean-up.

If this is what I have, I was wondering if additions to the list can cause exceptions?

```
std::list<std::size_t> dataList;
std::size_t t= GetSomeDataEmbeddedInSizeT();
// do some things
dataList.emplace_back(t); // can this generate exceptions?
```

It seems like exceptions are possible since emplace_back (or other addition APIs such as push_back) will construct a new object (in-place), but since std::size_t is like a primitive type, I wanted to confirm. And if exceptions are possible, what's the best way to prevent that from happening at addition time? I'd like to handle the exceptions at allocation time (i.e. GetSomeDataEmbeddedInSizeT()) so I can centralize all the exception-handling logic.

Thanks.

Comment: `vector` might still be a better choice than `list`, even if you never use random access.  `vector` has the lowest overhead (not counting `array`), and the main strength of `list` is efficiently inserting and erasing in the middle, which it sounds like you're not doing.

Comment: `std::list` maintains a linked list of nodes. A node is allocated on the heap whenever an element is added. That allocation may fail and throw an exception. With `vector`, if you can estimate the number of elements, you can `reserve()` sufficient amount of memory up front.

Comment: Igor, please let me clarify. I don't know the number of elements, but I do know that I will always increment by 1. Does this mean I should do this? `dataVector.reserve(dataVector.size() + 1)` and `dataVector.emplace_back(t)`. However, even if I use a vector and reserve, doesn't `emplace_back()` still construct a new object in-place and can still throw exceptions? Or I would have to use the array operator (`dataVector[dataVector.size()] = t`) to work around that?

Comment: If you don't know the number of elements, you shouldn't bother with `reserve` in general. You can still avoid some initial reallocations by reserving some amount of memory that you're fairly certain your application will consume. If you shoot high you'll avoid more reallocations but the flip side is you might use more memory than needed at times. It doesn't matter whether `size_t` is being `emplace`d, or `push_back`'d, the two are equivalent for builtin types. The `vector`/`list` will need to allocate more memory (if `size() == capacity()`) when you add a new element; that allocation may throw

Comment: I think you can indeed prevent an exception in `emplace_back` by using `reverse` (for vector, list does not have a `reserve`). That you need to do this might indicate a design issue, though. The exception guarantees for container classs in the C++ Standard are quite.. nebulous IMHO. They need to take into account what the allocator does (there's is a issue, probably a defect in the Standard, I had not yet time to report properly) and maybe even allow additional operations for debug implementations (checked iterators etc.). [to be continued..]

Comment: [continued] I think it's safe to assume that *if* the capacity is sufficient (vector), `emplace_back` will not throw an exception for sane implementations when using the standard allocator and fundamental value types such as `size_t`.

Comment: Per suggestions, I think I will change to using a vector and use `reserve` to prevent reallocation exceptions. And since the data type I am dealing with (std::size_t) doesn't have a constructor that throws, I wouldn't run into any exceptions when I use `emplace_back` to insert items to the vector.